Nginx not routing simultaneous requests hashed by a header variable to same upstream
I am using Nginx v1.27 as a load balancer for 2 upstream services. The routing is decided by nginx using hash on a header in the request.
Since the apps are part of a transaction, requests with a particular header value should always be sent to the same upstream.
This works fine in production, but during tests we see that when the tests start, nginx would route simultaneous requests received with the same header value to two different upstreams. Below is an example from the logs where it shows two simultaneous requests with the same header value (38d06ed9-f5b0-4654-88a8-b7466284f08d) being hashed onto different upstreams as indicated by their IP address.
127.0.0.1 - App [24/June/2024:20:11:27 +0000] "POST /targetApp/graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 24 "-" "Jersey/2.36 (HttpUrlConnection 17.0.11)" "-" "38d06ed9-f5b0-4654-88a8-b7466284f08d" "127.0.0.1:11901" "200"
127.0.0.1 - App [24/June/2024:20:11:27 +0000] "POST /targetApp/graphql HTTP/1.1" 200 11 "-" "Jersey/2.36 (HttpUrlConnection 17.0.11)" "-" "38d06ed9-f5b0-4654-88a8-b7466284f08d" "127.0.0.1:11900" "200"

We see this only for 1 request at the beginning of the test which causes a failure in the clients. However, subsequent requests with the same or different header value are handled correctly and no failure is seen anywhere in the stack.
Below is the Nginx Config for hash
upstream servers {
    server localhost:11900;
    server localhost:11901;

    hash $http_requestid consistent;
}

Could someone be able to advise if there's a way to handle this in Nginx?
